# How do I add multiple values from a Spinner to a TextView in Android?

Tags: java, android, spinner, android-spinner

I am building a simple grocery ordering App with firebase, where I want two spinners and a button.

- One Spinner for the item name and item price tag. (For example - 'Chips -5rs-')
- Second spinner for the quantity. (for Example - '5 packet')
- A button for taking the values from the spinners and putting it to the TextView below. (One item after the other.)

For Example, after adding several items from the spinners, the textview below should look like this. -

- Chips -5rs-       5 packet
- Biscuits -20rs-   20 packet
- Noodles -15rs-    2 packet

and so on..

How do I actually implement it? and if anyone could help me with actual java codes, I would be very thankful. I've also attached a picture below of how I am trying to Implement it. I am new to Android Development and I have keen interest in it.. any help would be deeply appreciated..

:) Thankyou ..

[This is the Screenshot of what I am trying to approach.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnKE4.png)

Comment: where is the spinner in your image

Comment: @aryanagarwal  The two boxes above the 'ADD ITEM' button are the two spinners. The first one contains the item list with price tags, and the other one contains item quantity.

Comment: I would be very happy if you first take an attempt at it and then ask , then it will be easy to review your code or embellish it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define  your string global

```
String priceTag,quantityTag;
```

then get value from spinner like this

```
yourSpinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

 @Override
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
 int position, long id) {
 
priceTag= yourSpinner1.spinnerDropDownView.getSelectedItem().toString();
 }

 @Override
 public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 
 }
 });
```

same as getting value from your second spinner

```
yourSpinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

 @Override
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
 int position, long id) {
 
priceTag= yourSpinner1.spinnerDropDownView.getSelectedItem().toString();
 }

 @Override
 public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 
 }
 });
```

and show data on button click like this

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) 
            { 
                yourtextViewId.setText(priceTag " - " quantityTag);
            } 
        });
```

Comment: This works sir.. but I have one more doubt.. sir this method adds only one item to the TextView. I wish to add multiple items on the textview on button click. (One after the other) how to do that?

Comment: Use append instead Of setText Or you can use listview.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it this way,
Firstly grab the values from both the spinners

```
//From spinner 1
String s1_val = spinner1.getSelectedItemsAsString(); 
//From spinner 2
String s2_val = spinner2.getSelectedItemsAsString();
```

Concat the values and set it to the text view.

```
//concat and set to textView
textView.setText(s1_val.concat(s2.val()));
```

Perform this on the onClick of **Add Items** button.

Comment: Thank you so much sir.. this worked. also  I want to add another value to my textview after adding the first value. how do i do that?

Comment: like.. one item is added. for ex - 'chips -5rs-     10 packet'. what should i do to add another item below it? in the textview?

Comment: Sir, How could I implement that? .. I am fairly new to android development.. Sir is there any way to contact you? I wish to mail you my codes sir.. thankyou :)

Comment: @VaibhavGupta you can use textView.append("your value"); instead of setting it every time on click. Refer [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#append(java.lang.CharSequence))

Comment: @VaibhavGupta Please visit my profile for the same.